# jQuery not showing custom error messages in PreSaveAction method of sharepoint 2013 list "New Form"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, csom, jquery-ui, newform

I am validating sharepoint list fields on PreSaveAction method of sharepoint list new form. I have done some customization and have put some labels with error messages under the sharepoint formfields. What should I do, any help would be appreciated.Below is my "New Form" code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var managerName;
    var flg;
    var managerLogId;
    var managerEmailId;
    var managerGUID;
    var vpName;
    var vpLoginId;
    var vpEmailId;
    var vpGUID;
    var technology;
    var projectStartDate;
    var projectEndDate;
    var clientContext;
    var startDatevalid = true;
    var endDatevalid = true;

    jQuery(document).ready(function()    
    {    
        //Set the Field to Read only and change its background colour    
        jQuery("input[title='TechnologiesIds']").attr("readonly","true").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');    

    });     

     function PreSaveAction()
     {
            // event.preventDefault();
        flg = 0;
        managerName = jQuery("input[title='ProjectManagerName']").val();    
        managerLogId = jQuery("input[title='ManagerLoginId']").val();   
        managerEmailId = jQuery("input[title='ManagerEmailId']").val();
        managerGUID = jQuery("input[title='ManagerGUID']").val();       

        vpName = jQuery("input[title='VPName']").val();
        vpLoginId = jQuery("input[title='VPLoginId']").val();
        vpEmailId = jQuery("input[title='VPEmailId']").val();
        vpGUID = jQuery("input[title='VPGUID']").val();


         var s = '';
         var cnt = 0;

        jQuery("#ctl00_ctl40_g_d08ffacb_a2dd_40a6_bde0_9f4991a04c0f_ff271_ctl00_ctl00_SelectResult option").each(function()
        {

            if(cnt == 1)
                s = s + " , " + jQuery(this).attr('value');
            else
                s = jQuery(this).attr('value');

            cnt = 1;

        });


        technology = s;

        jQuery("input[title='TechnologiesIds']").val(technology);



        projectStartDate = jQuery("input[title='ProjectStartDate']").val();
        projectEndDate = jQuery("input[title='ProjectEndDate']").val();

        if(projectStartDate != "" && projectEndDate != "")
        {
            startDatevalid = isDate(projectStartDate);
            endDatevalid = isDate(projectEndDate);
        }

        validateEmp();



           if(flg==1)
           {
                return false;
           }
           else
           {
                jQuery("#labelProjectManager").html("");                        
                jQuery("#labelManagerLogin").html("");          
                jQuery("#labelManagerEmail").html("");      
                jQuery("#labelManagerGUID").html("");   
                jQuery("#labelVPName").html(""); 
                jQuery("#labelVPLogin").html("");       
                jQuery("#labelVPEmail").html("");       
                jQuery("#labelVPGUID").html("");        
                return true;
           }    


     //     return true;

     }


     function validateEmp()
     {

            clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();     
            var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Profile');

            //********************************Code for Manager Validation************************************//     

            var mgrcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        /*  mgrcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='FullName' /><Value Type='Text'>"
                                +managerName+"</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='LoginName' /><Value Type='Text'>"
                                +managerLogId+"</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmailID' /><Value Type='Text'>"
                                +managerEmailId+"</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeGuid' /><Value Type='Text'>"
                                +managerGUID+"</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where></Query></View>");     */

            mgrcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FullName' /><Value Type='Text'>"+managerName+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
            this.mgrcollListItem = list.getItems(mgrcamlQuery);
            mgrcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='LoginName' /><Value Type='Text'>"+managerLogId+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
            this.mgrlogitem = list.getItems(mgrcamlQuery);
            mgrcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmailID' /><Value Type='Text'>"+managerEmailId+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
            this.mgrEmailitem = list.getItems(mgrcamlQuery);
            mgrcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeGuid' /><Value Type='Text'>"+managerGUID+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
            this.mgrGUIDitem = list.getItems(mgrcamlQuery);


            //***********************************Code for VP Validation**************************************//

            var vpcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        /*  vpcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='FullName' /><Value Type='Text'>"
                                +vpName+"</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='LoginName' /><Value Type='Text'>"
                                +vpLoginId+"</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmailID' /><Value Type='Text'>"
                                +vpEmailId+"</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeGuid' /><Value Type='Text'>"
                                +vpGUID+"</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where></Query></View>");      */

            vpcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FullName' /><Value Type='Text'>"+vpName+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
            this.vpcollListItem = list.getItems(vpcamlQuery);
            vpcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='LoginName' /><Value Type='Text'>"+vpLoginId+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
            this.vplogitem = list.getItems(vpcamlQuery);
            vpcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmailID' /><Value Type='Text'>"+vpEmailId+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
            this.vpEmailitem = list.getItems(vpcamlQuery);
            vpcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeGuid' /><Value Type='Text'>"+vpGUID+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
            this.vpGUIDitem = list.getItems(vpcamlQuery);


        //  alert("MngrName: "+managerName +"MngrLogin: "+managerLogId +"MngrEmail: "+managerEmailId +"MngrGUID: "+managerGUID +"VPName: "+vpName +"VPLoginID: "+vpLoginId+"VPEmailID: "+vpEmailId+"VPGUID: "+vpGUID+"Technology: "+technology+"StartDate: "+projectStartDate+"EndDate: "+projectEndDate);

            clientContext.load(mgrcollListItem);
            clientContext.load(mgrlogitem);
            clientContext.load(mgrEmailitem);
            clientContext.load(mgrGUIDitem);

            clientContext.load(vpcollListItem);
            clientContext.load(vplogitem);
            clientContext.load(vpEmailitem);
            clientContext.load(vpGUIDitem); 

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onValidateEmpSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onValidateEmpFailed));        

     }

     function onValidateEmpSucceeded(sender, args)
     {

            flg=0;
        //  alert("Succeeded: "+mgrcollListItem.get_count()+"VpCount: "+vpcollListItem.get_count());


            if(mgrcollListItem.get_count() == 0 && managerName != "")
            {
                flg = 1;
                alert(""+flg);
                //jQuery("#labelProjectManager").html("Invalid name. User does not exist.");    
                jQuery("#labelProjectManager").css("display", "block");
                alert("Invalid");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //jQuery("#labelProjectManager").html("");  
                jQuery("#labelProjectManager").css("display", "none");              
            }
            if(mgrlogitem.get_count() == 0 && managerLogId != "")
            {
                flg = 1;
                //jQuery("#labelManagerLogin").html("Invalid loginname. User does not exist."); 
                alert("Manager Login  "+mgrlogitem.get_count());                
            }
            else
            {
                //jQuery("#labelManagerLogin").html("");    
                alert("Manager Login  "+mgrlogitem.get_count());    
            }

            if(mgrEmailitem.get_count() == 0 && managerEmailId != "")
            {
                flg = 1;
                //jQuery("#labelManagerEmail").html("Invalid email id. User does not exist.");          
            }
            else
            {
                //jQuery("#labelManagerEmail").html("");
            }

            if(mgrGUIDitem.get_count() == 0 && managerGUID != "")
            {
                flg = 1;
                //jQuery("#labelManagerGUID").html("Invalid guid. User does not exist.");           
            }
            else
            {
                //jQuery("#labelManagerGUID").html("");
            }

            if(vpcollListItem.get_count() == 0 && vpName != "")
            {
                flg = 1;
                //jQuery("#labelVPName").html("Invalid name. User does not exist.");            
            }
            else
            {
                //jQuery("#labelVPName").html("");
            }

            if(vplogitem.get_count() == 0 && vpLoginId != "")
            {
                flg = 1;
                //jQuery("#labelVPLogin").html("Invalid loginname. User does not exist.");          
            }
            else
            {
                //jQuery("#labelVPLogin").html("");
            }

            if(vpEmailitem.get_count() == 0 && vpEmailId != "")
            {
                flg = 1;
                //jQuery("#labelVPEmail").html("Invalid email id. User does not exist.");           
            }
            else
            {
                //jQuery("#labelVPEmail").html("");
            }

            if(vpGUIDitem.get_count() == 0 && vpGUID != "")
            {
                flg = 1;
                //jQuery("#labelVPGUID").html("Invalid guid. User does not exist.");            
            }
            else
            {
                //jQuery("#labelVPGUID").html("");
            }           


            if(startDatevalid == "false")
            {
                flg = 1;
                //jQuery("#labelStartDate").html("Invalid date. Please enter appropriate date.");   
                alert(" "+startDatevalid);      
            }
            else
            {
                //jQuery("#labelStartDate").html("");
            }

            if(endDatevalid == false)
            {
                flg = 1;
                //jQuery("#labelEndDate").html("Invalid date. Please enter appropriate date.");             
            }
            else
            {
                //jQuery("#labelEndDate").html("");
            }

            if(startDatevalid == true && endDatevalid == true)
            {

                var projStart = new Date(projectStartDate);
                var projEnd = new Date(projectEndDate);

                var startDate = projStart.getDate() + "/" + projStart.getMonth() + "/" + projStart.getFullYear();
                var endDate = projEnd.getDate() + "/" + projEnd.getMonth() + "/" + projEnd.getFullYear();

            //  alert("Start: "+projStart+"End: "+projEnd);

                if(projStart > projEnd)
                {

                    flg = 1;
                    //jQuery("#labelDateValid").html("Start date should be smaller than end date.");
                    alert("Start: "+ projStart.getFullYear() +"End: " + projEnd.getFullYear());

                }
                else
                {
                    ///jQuery("#labelDateValid").html("");

                }
            }



                if(managerName == "")
                {
                    flg = 1;
                    //jQuery("#labelProjectManager").html("You must specify a value for this required field.");                         
                }
                if(managerLogId == "")
                {           
                    flg = 1;                        
                    //jQuery("#labelManagerLogin").html("You must specify a value for this required field.");           

                }
                if(managerEmailId == "")
                {
                    flg = 1;
                    //jQuery("#labelManagerEmail").html("You must specify a value for this required field.");       

                }
                if(managerGUID == "")
                {
                    flg = 1;
                    //jQuery("#labelManagerGUID").html("You must specify a value for this required field.");
                }
                if(vpName == "")
                {           
                    flg = 1;
                    ///jQuery("#labelVPName").html("You must specify a value for this required field.");                
                }
                if(vpLoginId == "")
                {       
                    flg = 1;
                    //jQuery("#labelVPLogin").html("You must specify a value for this required field.");        

                }
                if(vpEmailId == "")
                {   
                    flg = 1;
                    //jQuery("#labelVPEmail").html("You must specify a value for this required field.");        

                }
                if(vpGUID == "")
                {
                    flg = 1;
                    //jQuery("#labelVPGUID").html("You must specify a value for this required field.");         
                }
                if(projectStartDate == "")
                {
                    flg = 1;
                    //jQuery("#labelStartDate").html("You must specify a value for this required field.");      
                }
                if(projectEndDate == "")
                {
                    flg = 1;
                    //jQuery("#labelEndDate").html("You must specify a value for this required field.");        
                }



     }

     function onValidateEmpFailed(sender, args)
     { 
         alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
     }


    function isDate(txtDate)
    {
        var currVal = txtDate;
        if(currVal == '')
            return false;

        var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;

        //Declare Regex
        var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?

        if (dtArray == null) 
            return false;

        //Checks for dd/mm/yyyy format.

        dtMonth = dtArray[3];
        dtDay= dtArray[1];
        dtYear = dtArray[5];    

        if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12) 
            return false;
        else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay> 31) 
            return false;
        else if ((dtMonth==4 || dtMonth==6 || dtMonth==9 || dtMonth==11) && dtDay ==31) 
            return false;
        else if (dtMonth == 2) 
        {
            var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
            if (dtDay> 29 || (dtDay ==29 && !isleap)) 
                    return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling `PreSaveAction` method ?

Comment: we don't need to call PreSaveAction method. It is called by sharepoint on submit button click of sharepoint new form

Comment: In `PreSaveAction` method, you are calling `validateEmp` method which contains `executeQueryAsync` method. So it might be the reason that before `onValidateEmpSucceeded` method completes, the `PreSaveAction` method returns true and no validation messages are shown.

Comment: But the same code was working yesterday & showing error messages, and today it is giving me the issue, and all my validations are working right, I am only having the issue with error messages as they are not shown when the wrong data is entered

Comment: Have a look at jQuery Deferred to wait for callback. As @yayati stated, PreSaveAction will not wait for your asynch call

Comment: Are you sure `PreSaveAction` is global? Have you tried `window.PreSaveAction = function(){ ... };`?

Comment: @erikib, Can you show me how to implement that, I am not sure but it should be global.